# android Visualizer on min api 8

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-support-library

i'd like to use Visualizer on an application defined in the manifest as min api 8.
Visualizer demands min api 9, which doesn't work in my case. 
I tried looking for a support library containing it, but failed to find so.

> http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4

I'm trying to load a MediaPlayer music track and add a Visualizer to it. 
There's no point of posting any code, since the reason is pretty obvious here :)

Did anyone encountered this issue and find a result for it ?

Thanks.

Comment: "defined in the manifest as min api 8" -- note that, at the time of this writing, API Level 8 is down to 1.3% of market share, with trace amounts at lower levels: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possibilities you have:

1. Port the existing Visualizer to lower platforms. This will be non-trivial due to the native part (C++ code) you would have to port as well.
2. Use an open-source project. There is quite a range of open source components you could choose from: https://github.com/search?q=android+visualizer&ref=cmdform
3. Build your own Visualizer.